# Flexbox - top aligning content

Tags: css, flexbox

```css
.content {
  display: flex;
  flex-flow: row wrap;
  height: 800px;
  align-items: flex-start;
}

.header {
  background-color: magenta;
  flex: 1 100%;
}

.body {
  background-color: blue;
  color: white;
  flex: 1 0;
}

.nav {
  background-color: green;
}
```

```html
<div class="content">
  <div class="header">
    <h1>Header</h1>
  </div>
  <div class="body">
    <h2>Body</h2>
  </div>
  <div class="nav">
    <h2>Navigation</h2>
  </div>
</div>
```

I would like to produce the following layout:

[image]

My Markup is restricted to the following format:

```
<div class="content">
  <div class="header"><h1>Header</h1></div>
  <div class="body"><h2>Body</h2></div>
  <div class="nav"><h2>Navigation</h2></div>
</div>
```

Currently, I'm able to produce the desired layout but only with a gap between the header and the following divs. I've created a [codepen](https://codepen.io/chut319/pen/ZEYOKmJ) with my workings so far.

I know I'm missing something obvious, but please could someone advise how to 'top align' the body and navigation divs? I've tried justify-content and align-items options to no avail.

Many thanks!

Comment: @Paulie_D - thanks for the heads-up. I've edited the original question accordingly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I knew it was something obvious. I was missing `align-content` on the `content` div.

Answer (score 0):

```
.content {
  flex-flow: row wrap;
  height: 100px;
  display:flex;
}

.header {
  background-color: magenta;
  flex: 1 100%;
}

.body {
  background-color: blue;
  color: white;
  flex: 1 0;
}

.nav {
  background-color: green;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Just remove the fixed height from the flexbox. Currently your flexbox items are trying to wrap the second row halfway down the total height of the box:

```css
.content {
  display: flex;
  flex-flow: row wrap;
  /*height: 400px;*/
  align-items: flex-start;
}

.header {
  background-color: magenta;
  flex: 1 100%;
}

.body {
  background-color: blue;
  color: white;
  flex: 1 0 0;
}

.nav {
  background-color: green;
}
```

```html
<div class="content">
  <div class="header"><h1>Header</h1></div>
  <div class="body"><h2>Body</h2></div>
  <div class="nav"><h2>Navigation</h2></div>
</div>
```

Comment: Hi @symlink, thanks for the reply, but the content needs to have a height attribute. Unfortunately, I haven't got any control over the markup, just the css. I've resolved the issue though - I stupidly left out the align-content attribute on the .content div.

Answer (score 0):

You can try like this:

```css
  * {
    box-sizing: border-box; 
  }
  body {
    display: flex;
    min-height: 100vh;
    flex-direction: column;
    margin: 0;
  }
  #main {
    display: flex;
    flex: 1;
  }
  #main > article {
    flex: 1;
    order: 1;
  }

  #main > aside {
    flex: 0 0 20vw;
    background: beige;
    order: 2;
  }
  
  header {
    background: yellowgreen;
    height: 20vh;
  }
```

```html
  <body>
  <header>Header</header>
  <div id="main">
    <article>Article</article>  
    <aside>Aside</aside>
  </div>
</body>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this code

```css
.content {
 display: flex;
 flex-flow: row wrap;
 height: 400px;
}

.header {
 background-color: magenta;
 flex: 1 100%;
 align-items: center;
 display: flex
}

.body {
 background-color: blue;
 color: white;
 flex: 1 0;
 align-items: center;
 display: flex
}

.nav {
 background-color: green;
 align-items: center;
 display: flex
}
```

```html
 <div class="content">
  <div class="header"><h1>Header</h1></div>
  <div class="body"><h2>Body</h2></div>
  <div class="nav"><h2>Navigation</h2></div>
</div>
```

: